# Проблема с консолью git при работе с хостингом

Tags: mysql, командная-строка

Как убрать стрелку -> и вернуться в mysql>, не перезапуская консоль?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и при чём тут git?

Comment: А вообще, вы попросту забыли ввести `;` если я правильно помню синтаксис SQL

Answer (score 0):

-> ; (Нажимаешь Enter)
*You have an error in your SQL syntax.........*
mysql>